# ANTLR3 String Literals and Disallowing Nested Comments

Tags: regex, antlr, token, antlr3, antlrv3ide

I've recently been tasked with writing an ANTLR3 grammar for a fictional language. Everything else seems fine, but I've a couple of minor issues which I could do with some help with:

1) Comments are between `'/*'` and `'*/'`, and may not be nested. I know how to implement comments themselves (`'/*' .* '*/'`), but how would I go about disallowing their nesting?

2) String literals are defined as any sequence of characters (except for double quotes and new lines) in between a pair of double quotes. They can only be used in an output statement. I attempted to define this thus:

```
output : OUTPUT (STRINGLIT | IDENT) ;
STRINGLIT : '"' ~('\r' | '\n' | '"')* '"' ;
```

For some reason, however, the parser accepts

```
OUTPUT "Hello,
World!"
```

and tokenises it as `"Hello, \nWorld`. Where the exclamation mark or closing `"` went I have no idea. Something to do with whitespace maybe?

```
WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\n' | '\r' | '\f' )+ { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
```

Any advice would be much appreciated - thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The form you wrote already disallows nested comments. The token will stop at the first instance of `*/`, even if multiple `/*` sequences appeared in the comment. To *allow* nested comments you have to write a lexer rule to specifically treat the nesting.
2. The problem here is `STRINGLIT` does not allow a string to be split across multiple lines. Without seeing the rest of your lexer rules, I cannot tell you how this will be tokenized, but it's clear from the `STRINGLIT` rule you gave that the sample input is not a valid string.

NOTE: Your input given in the original question was not clear, so I reformatted it in an attempt to show the exact input you were using. Can you verify that my edit properly represents the input?

Comment: Thanks so much 280Z28 - you're entirely right about the non-nested nature, I can't believe I didn't spot that! Your edit does properly represent the input - thank you!
I need to clarify point 2: a STRINGLIT should NOT be allowed to be split across multiple lines, but using the syntax I have defined, the interpreter is allowing me to do so, with the output displayed above. I'm not sure at all why this is the case!

Comment: The ANTLR 3 *interpreter* frequently produces incorrect results. Have you tried running the actual parser instead?